# Telegram event adding new message in chat

Tags: chat, telegram

I explore webogram and want make analyzer of each messages that users send in chat. How catch event of adding new message from any user?

Comment: What is add message mean?

Comment: When any massage from any user appiar in chat/

Comment: Do you know programming?

Comment: Yes. I want create app that make analyzer of messages of all users in chats in real time (word statistics and so on). When user add new message in chat, immediately run analitic function. But I can't catch this event to start this function.

Comment: I mean event call next function:
function NewMessageFromUser (idUser, messageContent) {
    alert ("User with ID #"+idUser+" add in chat next message:"'+messageContent+"'");
}